# Matching exactly two consecutive spaces in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to match exactly two consecutive spaces using `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText()` and replace them with a single space.

Unfortunately, it only supports some of regex (https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

I've tried `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText("[^ ] {2}[^ ]", " ")` but that matches the characters sourrounding the text aswell.

I've tried `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText("([^ ]) {2}([^ ])", "$1 $2")` but this outputs "$1 $2" rather then "*character* *character*"

I've tried `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText(" {2}", " ")` but that also matches two spaces within a greater group of spaces.

Comment: Can't you just do `replaceText("  ", " ")`?

Comment: @Jack Bashford won't that match only one space?

Comment: It's a problem with StackOverflow's comment markdown syntax, it seems to replace duplicate typed spaces with a single space. Not sure if there's a workaround. (I"m sure @Jack typed two spaces into the comment box there) eg `foo     bar` <- I typed 5 spaces between `foo` and `bar`

Comment: @CertainPerformance In that case still no because I get an error when using replaceText("  ", " "), so I used replaceText(" {2}", " "), should be the same. The issue with that is it also matches two consecutive spaces that are within a greater group of spaces, which I don't want.

Comment: You might try &nbsp;

Comment: Must you use regex? Because in this case `.split("  ").join(" ")` might work. (2 spaces for the split)

Comment: Try `"\b {2}\b"` if the spaces must appear between letters and digits.

Comment: Also try `replaceText("[^ ]( {2})[^ ]", " ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was difficult (for me) to write a single regular expression for required replacements, because surrounding characters (non-spaces) were also replaced each time. Moreover, in general case we should take into account special cases when spaces position is at the very beginning of the string or at the end.

As a result I suggest 2 functions for all kinds of replacements below:

```
function replaceDoubleSpace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var count = replaceWithPattern('^  $', body);
  Logger.log(count + ' replacement(s) done for the entire string');
  count = replaceWithPattern('[^ ]{1}  [^ ]{1}', body);
  Logger.log(count + ' replacement(s) done inside the string');
  count = replaceWithPattern('^  [^ ]{1}', body);
  Logger.log(count + ' replacement(s) done at the beginning of the string');
  count = replaceWithPattern('[^ ]{1}  $', body);
  Logger.log(count + ' replacement(s) done at the end of the string');
}


function replaceWithPattern(pat, body) {
  var patterns = [];
  var count = 0;
  while (true) {
    var range = body.findText(pat);
    if (range == null) break;
    var text = range.getElement().asText().getText();
    var pos = range.getStartOffset() + 1; 
    text = text.substring(0, pos) + text.substring(pos + 1);
    range.getElement().asText().setText(text);
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Of course, the first function may be simplified, but it becomes less readable in this case:

```
function replaceDoubleSpace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var count = replaceWithPattern('^  $|[^ ]{1}  [^ ]{1}|^  [^ ]{1}|[^ ]{1}  $', body);
  Logger.log(count + ' replacement(s) done');
}
```